# SyntaxError: Unexpected token on Basic Demo (Fine on MAMP / Error on Server)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, upload

My Hosting company have updated their SQL version and ever since i'm getting a

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token<

I have just set-up the basic demo which works fine on my local MAMP set-up but when I try on the server it spits out this message !

It is driving me insane !

Simon

Comment: A bit more information/code wouldn't hurt

Comment: Updated the SQL version or PHP version? Post your code, guessing isn't that fun.

Comment: This is now fixed, sorry for not posting the code.

I had Wordpress installed in a sub-directory and the .htaccess was stopping the JSON Callback function. This is related with 404 errors.